# Vertically stretched background aligned to center

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, stretch

I want to have a background image stretched vertically and positioned center of page.

I thought it would be simple, but it seems I cannot center it in any way. Here is my CSS code:

HTML

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="bkg.jpg" class="stretch" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -999;
}

.stretch {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #525252;
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can have this background centered? It's now aligned to the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works how you want it.

It stretches the image vertically and positions it in the center.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8aZr/)

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #525252;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: url('bk.jpg') center / auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want support for older browsers, see this [**jsFiddle solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/yBDFV/4/). It uses the `img` tag as opposed to setting the image via `background-image`.

Comment: No, that doesn't keep aspect ratio of the original image, unfortunately.

Here is my original code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Ubju/

My background image is 1280 by 1024 and I need to stretch it only vertically, align it horizontally AND keep its aspect ratio. Tough problem :)

Comment: @Alex Why do you expect to keep the aspect ratio if you want to stretch it vertically? I guess I do not understand what you want.

Comment: Maybe my English is bad. I want it 100% vertical and auto horizontally, thus keeping aspect ratio. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome :) I had no idea you could specify `auto` via the `background` declaration.

Comment: See: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-image .. I will see if this can be achieved via the `img` tag and avoid using `background-image`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38456/discussion-between-alex-and-joshc)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:-

```
body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:1000px;
    background-color: #525252;
}
```

OR

In this case you need to remove "`position: fixed;`":

```
#background {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:1000px;
}
```

You need to give some fixed width to body or the DIV.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My image is 1280px wide to start with, but if it stretches then the "width" value for the body is of no use, since it will not align it properly.

Comment: If I remove "position", it will not stretch vertically anymore.